# Compare sum of nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create request for compare sum nested properties with non-nested property

Mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "publishers": {
            "properties": {
                "Accounts": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "FollowersCount": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "TotalSubscribers": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find documents where sum of Accounts.FollowersCount not equal with TotalSubscribers.

How to do it?

PS:
I am trying create something like this:

```
{
    "_source": [
        "TotalSubscribers",
        "Accounts.FollowersCount"
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": {
                        "source": "int total = 0; for (int i = 0; i < doc['Accounts'].length; ++i) {total += doc['Accounts'][i].FollowersCount;} return total == doc['TotalSubscribers'];",
                        "lang": "painless"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Same problem when i move script into nested block. Then i can't get access to TotalSubscribers

Update1:
ES version = 6.8

**Request1** :

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "PublisherId": 349438
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.TotalSubscribers = ctx._source.Accounts.stream().map(a -> a.FollowersCount).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "runtime error",
                "script_stack": [
                    "java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$summingInt$11(Collectors.java:467)",
                    "java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)",
                    "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)",
                    "java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)",
                    "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)",
                    "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)",
                    "java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)",
                    "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)",
                    "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)",
                    "a -> a.FollowersCount).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));",
                    "                                                     ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "ctx._source.TotalSubscribers = ctx._source.Accounts.stream().map(a -> a.FollowersCount).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));",
                "lang": "painless"
            }
        ],
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
            "java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$summingInt$11(Collectors.java:467)",
            "java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)",
            "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)",
            "java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)",
            "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)",
            "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)",
            "java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)",
            "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)",
            "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)",
            "a -> a.FollowersCount).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));",
            "                                                     ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "ctx._source.TotalSubscribers = ctx._source.Accounts.stream().map(a -> a.FollowersCount).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));",
        "lang": "painless",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": null
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

**Request2**:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "PublisherId": 349438
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "int total = 0; for(int i=0;i<=ctx._source.Accounts.size()-1;i++){total += ctx._source.Accounts[i].FollowersCount} ctx._source['TotalSubscribers'] = total"
    }
}
```

Error too, near     "total += ctx._source.Accounts[i].FollowersCount

**Request3**:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "PublisherId": 349438
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "int total = 0; for(int i=0;i<=ctx._source.Accounts.size()-1;i++){total += i} ctx._source['TotalSubscribers'] = total"
    }
}
```

Works fine, after update totalSubscribers == count Account items. But need get Accounts property, not i...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be solvable through a `script` query, but as it is not possible to access nested documents inside a `script` query, you have to proceed differently. In these cases, it is always much easier to add a new field in the top-level that contains the sum of `FollowersCount`, that you can name `TotalFollowersCount`.

First you need to create that field using the `_update_by_query` endpoint, like this:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
    ctx._source.TotalFollowersCount = ctx._source.Accounts
      .stream()
      .map(a -> a.FollowersCount ?: 0)
      .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
    """
  }
}
```

Then you can use a `script` query in order to find problematic documents:

```
GET your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc.TotalFollowersCount.value != doc.TotalSubscribers.value"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ```{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "PublisherId": 349438
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.TotalSubscribers = ctx._source.Accounts.stream().map(a -> a.FollowersCount).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));"
    }
}```

error:
"a -> a.FollowersCount).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));",
            "                                                     ^---- HERE"


Error near Integer::intValue

Comment: Maybe update your question with the full error, it's more legible... Also can you tell which version of ES you're using?

Comment: I've updated the update by query script, please try again

Comment: Fantastic! Great it helped!